# How to update state - (store result in database) using storm

Tags: java, database, state, apache-storm

I have problem with update state in my topology (local mode) - I want to write a result in database:

Run topology this way:

```
TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();

StateFactory stateFactoryDB = new LocationDBFactory();
MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout spout = new MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout();

Stream globalSubmittedMessageStream = topology.newStream("globalSubmittedMessageStream", spout).parallelismHint(1);

globalSubmittedMessageStream
.project(new Fields("stormTxid","bookingId", "timestamp", "messagesSubmitted", "messagesFailed"))
    .each(new Fields("bookingId"), new FilterNotZero() )
    .each(new Fields("timestamp"), new FilterNull())
    .each(new Fields("bookingId", "messagesSubmitted"),new PrintFilter("success submitted - start: "))
    .partitionPersist(
        stateFactoryDB, 
        new Fields("stormTxid","bookingId", "timestamp", "messagesFailed", "messagesSubmitted"), 
        new LocationDBStateUpdater(),
        new Fields("test")
    );
```

Data are correctly got from database (by MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout) and emitted by each filter by only data from first transactions are saved to stateFactoryDB (LocationDBFactory) by partitionPersist, non another transactions are updated.

Code for the updateState methods from the LocationDBStateUpdater class:

```
public void updateState(LocationDB state, List<TridentTuple> tuples,TridentCollector collector) {
 for(TridentTuple tuple : tuples){
  LOG.debug("^%*&^$&^#&%$@#^%$#^%$*&^%(&^%(&^%(&%(&%&  > {} ", tuple);
 }
 state.save(tuples, collector);
}
```

Code for the LocationDB class:

```
public void beginCommit(Long txid) {
 LOG.info("beginCommit...... txid: {}", txid);
}

@Override
public void commit(Long txid) {
 LOG.info("commit...... txid: {}", txid);
}

public void save(List<TridentTuple> tuples, TridentCollector collector) {
 LOG.info("save ......... START");      
 for(TridentTuple tuple : tuples){
  LOG.info("#@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ TEST TUPLE: {}", tuple);
 }      
 for(TridentTuple t : tuples){
  collector.emit(new Values("TRUE"));
 }
 LOG.info("save ......... END");
}
```

Logs:

```
6056 [Thread-10] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Worker f818dc1b-0f34-43f8-b70a-a12afaef9d88 for storm test-topology-1-1373534952 on cbe0de9a-4cef-483f-bc11-77a15b0ad6f9:4 has finished loading 
6073 [Thread-23] INFO  c.n.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting 
0    [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x13fcd101957000d, likely client has closed socket
6098 [Thread-23] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt spout0:(5) 
6098 [Thread-17] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt $spoutcoord-spout0:(2) 
6106 [Thread-25] INFO  c.n.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting 
32   [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x13fcd101957000f, likely client has closed socket
6120 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - getCoordinator !!! 
6120 [Thread-25] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Opened spout $mastercoord-bg0:(1) 
6122 [Thread-25] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Activating spout $mastercoord-bg0:(1) 
6122 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 1 !!! 
6225 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Opening JDBC Connection 
6237 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 2 !!! 
6288 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 3 !!! 
6341 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 4 !!! 
6460 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 5 !!! 
6511 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 6 !!! 
6562 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 7 !!! 
6670 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 8 !!! 
6725 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 9 !!! 
6776 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 10 !!! 
6828 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 11 !!! 
6879 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 12 !!! 
6931 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 13 !!! 
6982 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 14 !!! 
7034 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 15 !!! 
7085 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 16 !!! 
7136 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 17 !!! 
7187 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 18 !!! 
7238 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 19 !!! 
7289 [Thread-25] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - Coordinator - isReady method, txid: 20 !!! 
8238 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Created connection 19739814. 
8391 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ooo Using Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
8392 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ==>  Preparing: SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM msisdn_status  
8446 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ==> Parameters:  
8619 [Thread-23] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.StatusManager - Max id: 2902288 
8620 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
8773 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
8773 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Returned connection 19739814 to pool. 
8774 [Thread-23] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - emitPartitionBatch, startId: 0, endId: 50, max id: 2902288, TransactionAttempt: 1:0, partition: 0  
8779 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Opening JDBC Connection 
8779 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Checked out connection 19739814 from pool. 
8780 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Setting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
8931 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getSubmittedStatistics - ooo Using Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
8931 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getSubmittedStatistics - ==>  Preparing: SELECT sum(f.messages_submitted) as messages_submitted, sum(f.messages_failed) as messages_failed, fb.booking_id,f.classification_id,f.submission_account_id, f.timestamp FROM ( SELECT count(IF(msisdn_status.status >= 0, 1, NULL)) as messages_submitted, count(IF(msisdn_status.status < 0, 1, NULL)) as messages_failed, msisdn_status.flight_id, date(msisdn_status.timestamp) as timestamp, msisdn_status.classification_id, msisdn_status.submission_account_id FROM msisdn_status WHERE ( msisdn_status.id > ? AND msisdn_status.id <= ? AND msisdn_status.timestamp IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY flight_id, timestamp, classification_id, submission_account_id ) f LEFT JOIN jupiter.flight_reference fr on f.flight_id = fr.flight_id LEFT JOIN jupiterbs.flightboard fb on fb.flight_reference = fr.flight_reference GROUP BY f.timestamp, fb.booking_id, f.classification_id, f.submission_account_id;  
8932 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getSubmittedStatistics - ==> Parameters: 0(Long), 50(Long) 
9141 [Thread-23] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.StatusManager -  Submitted List [MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-27 00:00:00.0, -1, -1, 6, 0}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-27 00:00:00.0, 1, -1, 0, 7}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-27 00:00:00.0, 2, -1, 0, 2}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, -1, -1, 23, 0}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 1, -1, 0, 8}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 2, -1, 0, 4}] 
9141 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
9292 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
9292 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Returned connection 19739814 to pool. 
9295 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 0]  
9295 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 7]  
9295 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Opening JDBC Connection 
9295 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 2]  
9296 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Checked out connection 19739814 from pool. 
9296 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Setting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
9296 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 0]  
9296 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 8]  
9296 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 4]  
9298 [Thread-21] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.db.LocationDB - beginCommit...... txid: 1 
9298 [Thread-21] DEBUG c.a.storm.db.LocationDBStateUpdater - ^%*&^$&^#&%$@#^%$#^%$*&^%(&^%(&^%(&%(&%&  > [1, 29, 2011-01-27 00:00:00.0, 6, 0]  
9299 [Thread-21] DEBUG c.a.storm.db.LocationDBStateUpdater - ^%*&^$&^#&%$@#^%$#^%$*&^%(&^%(&^%(&%(&%&  > [1, 29, 2011-01-27 00:00:00.0, 0, 7]  
9299 [Thread-21] DEBUG c.a.storm.db.LocationDBStateUpdater - ^%*&^$&^#&%$@#^%$#^%$*&^%(&^%(&^%(&%(&%&  > [1, 29, 2011-01-27 00:00:00.0, 0, 2]  
9299 [Thread-21] DEBUG c.a.storm.db.LocationDBStateUpdater - ^%*&^$&^#&%$@#^%$#^%$*&^%(&^%(&^%(&%(&%&  > [1, 29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 23, 0]  
9299 [Thread-21] DEBUG c.a.storm.db.LocationDBStateUpdater - ^%*&^$&^#&%$@#^%$#^%$*&^%(&^%(&^%(&%(&%&  > [1, 29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 0, 8]  
9299 [Thread-21] DEBUG c.a.storm.db.LocationDBStateUpdater - ^%*&^$&^#&%$@#^%$#^%$*&^%(&^%(&^%(&%(&%&  > [1, 29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 0, 4]  
9299 [Thread-21] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.db.LocationDB - save ......... START 
9300 [Thread-21] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.db.LocationDB - #@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ TEST TUPLE: [1, 29, 2011-01-27 00:00:00.0, 6, 0] 
9300 [Thread-21] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.db.LocationDB - #@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ TEST TUPLE: [1, 29, 2011-01-27 00:00:00.0, 0, 7] 
9300 [Thread-21] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.db.LocationDB - #@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ TEST TUPLE: [1, 29, 2011-01-27 00:00:00.0, 0, 2] 
9300 [Thread-21] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.db.LocationDB - #@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ TEST TUPLE: [1, 29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 23, 0] 
9300 [Thread-21] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.db.LocationDB - #@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ TEST TUPLE: [1, 29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 0, 8] 
9300 [Thread-21] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.db.LocationDB - #@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ TEST TUPLE: [1, 29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 0, 4] 
9301 [Thread-21] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.db.LocationDB - save ......... END 
9301 [Thread-21] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.db.LocationDB - commit...... txid: 1 
9447 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ooo Using Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
9447 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ==>  Preparing: SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM msisdn_status  
9447 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ==> Parameters:  
9599 [Thread-23] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.StatusManager - Max id: 2902288 
9599 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
9750 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
9750 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Returned connection 19739814 to pool. 
9751 [Thread-23] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - emitPartitionBatch, startId: 50, endId: 100, max id: 2902288, TransactionAttempt: 2:0, partition: 0  
9751 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Opening JDBC Connection 
9751 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Checked out connection 19739814 from pool. 
9751 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Setting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
9902 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getSubmittedStatistics - ooo Using Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
9902 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getSubmittedStatistics - ==>  Preparing: SELECT sum(f.messages_submitted) as messages_submitted, sum(f.messages_failed) as messages_failed, fb.booking_id,f.classification_id,f.submission_account_id, f.timestamp FROM ( SELECT count(IF(msisdn_status.status >= 0, 1, NULL)) as messages_submitted, count(IF(msisdn_status.status < 0, 1, NULL)) as messages_failed, msisdn_status.flight_id, date(msisdn_status.timestamp) as timestamp, msisdn_status.classification_id, msisdn_status.submission_account_id FROM msisdn_status WHERE ( msisdn_status.id > ? AND msisdn_status.id <= ? AND msisdn_status.timestamp IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY flight_id, timestamp, classification_id, submission_account_id ) f LEFT JOIN jupiter.flight_reference fr on f.flight_id = fr.flight_id LEFT JOIN jupiterbs.flightboard fb on fb.flight_reference = fr.flight_reference GROUP BY f.timestamp, fb.booking_id, f.classification_id, f.submission_account_id;  
9903 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getSubmittedStatistics - ==> Parameters: 50(Long), 100(Long) 
10087 [Thread-23] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.StatusManager -  Submitted List [MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, -1, -1, 35, 0}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 1, -1, 0, 6}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 2, -1, 0, 5}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 11, -1, 4, 0}] 
10087 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
10238 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
10238 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Returned connection 19739814 to pool. 
10239 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Opening JDBC Connection 
10239 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 0]  
10239 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Checked out connection 19739814 from pool. 
10239 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 6]  
10239 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 5]  
10239 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 0]  
10239 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Setting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
10393 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ooo Using Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
10393 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ==>  Preparing: SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM msisdn_status  
10393 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ==> Parameters:  
10546 [Thread-23] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.StatusManager - Max id: 2902288 
10546 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
10698 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
10699 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Returned connection 19739814 to pool. 
10699 [Thread-23] INFO  c.a.s.MessageSubmittedOpaqueTransSpout - emitPartitionBatch, startId: 100, endId: 150, max id: 2902288, TransactionAttempt: 3:0, partition: 0  
10699 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Opening JDBC Connection 
10699 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Checked out connection 19739814 from pool. 
10699 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Setting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
10853 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getSubmittedStatistics - ooo Using Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
10854 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getSubmittedStatistics - ==>  Preparing: SELECT sum(f.messages_submitted) as messages_submitted, sum(f.messages_failed) as messages_failed, fb.booking_id,f.classification_id,f.submission_account_id, f.timestamp FROM ( SELECT count(IF(msisdn_status.status >= 0, 1, NULL)) as messages_submitted, count(IF(msisdn_status.status < 0, 1, NULL)) as messages_failed, msisdn_status.flight_id, date(msisdn_status.timestamp) as timestamp, msisdn_status.classification_id, msisdn_status.submission_account_id FROM msisdn_status WHERE ( msisdn_status.id > ? AND msisdn_status.id <= ? AND msisdn_status.timestamp IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY flight_id, timestamp, classification_id, submission_account_id ) f LEFT JOIN jupiter.flight_reference fr on f.flight_id = fr.flight_id LEFT JOIN jupiterbs.flightboard fb on fb.flight_reference = fr.flight_reference GROUP BY f.timestamp, fb.booking_id, f.classification_id, f.submission_account_id;  
10854 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getSubmittedStatistics - ==> Parameters: 100(Long), 150(Long) 
11036 [Thread-23] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.StatusManager -  Submitted List [MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, -1, -1, 39, 0}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 1, -1, 0, 4}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 2, -1, 0, 1}, MsisdnStatus{29, 2011-01-28 00:00:00.0, 11, -1, 4, 2}] 
11036 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
11188 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
11189 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Returned connection 19739814 to pool. 
11189 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Opening JDBC Connection 
11189 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Checked out connection 19739814 from pool. 
11189 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Setting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
11190 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 0]  
11190 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 4]  
11190 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 1]  
11190 [Thread-21] INFO  c.a.storm.utils.PrintFilter - success submitted - start:  > [29, 2]  
11340 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ooo Using Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
11341 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ==>  Preparing: SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM msisdn_status  
11341 [Thread-23] DEBUG c.a.s.d.J.getMaxSubmittedId - ==> Parameters:  
11494 [Thread-23] INFO  c.archermobile.storm.StatusManager - Max id: 2902288 
11494 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
11646 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@12d34a6] 
11646 [Thread-23] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Returned connection 19739814 to pool. 
..............
```

On the beginning of this logs you can see additional information like:

```
0    [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  - EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x13fcd101957000d, likely client has closed socket
```

My problem can be connected with this warning? What do I do wrong?
Maybe there is another way to store result in database?

Comment: storm v0.8.2Do you need another information?

Comment: Why not use storm-jdbc?
http://storm.apache.org/documentation/storm-jdbc.html